# Summary of runtimes from large table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a table with 500 million rows, and 25,000 unique tag_ids, it looks like:

```
tag_id  event_time  event_value reason_type
10087   2011-01-01 04:31:28.000 0   NULL
10087   2011-01-01 18:03:28.000 0   NULL
10087   2011-01-02 07:35:27.000 1   NULL
10087   2011-01-02 21:07:27.000 0   NULL
10087   2011-01-03 10:39:27.000 1   NULL
10087   2011-01-04 00:11:27.000 1   NULL
```

For a specific tag_id, the 0 represents the motor was off, and 1 the motor was on.

The system polls the status of the motor at random times, or when the status changes.

I want to make a summary, that shows how much time the motor was running.  Like:

```
tag_id  date runtime_mins
10087 2011-01-04 3600
10087 2011-01-05 2456
10087 2011-01-06 2321
```

Thanks for your ideas and help!

Comment: How long does a SELECT ... GROUP BY ... take (with indexes on Tag_id and date)? How often you want this result to be generated? If you want speedy results on a frequent basis, you create a trigger that populates another table with the desired aggregation as soon as a new record is added, however, this may cause a slight delay while adding new data.

Comment: If the new entry is added when there is  a change  in event_value (0 to 1 (or) 1 to 0). Or on a interval basis??

Comment: Its not the SELECT that is the problem, its making the runtime.  The new entry can happen at a random time interval (state stays the same), or when the state changes.

Comment: 1 means motor was turned on and 0 means motor was turned off and you want the difference between the on and off time in minutes. correct?

Comment: 1 is on, 0 is off.  Total 'on' time per day.

Comment: can you update the expected output for given sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE
        (
          tag_id INT ,
          event_time DATETIME ,
          event_value INT
        )
    INSERT  INTO @tmp
    VALUES  ( 10087, '2011-01-01 04:31:28.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-01 10:31:28.000', 0 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-01 18:03:28.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 07:35:27.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 21:07:27.000', 0 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-03 10:39:27.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-04 00:11:27.000', 1 )
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    --create temp table for data 'turned on'
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Turnedon') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Turnedon
    SELECT  T.tag_id ,
            CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate ,
            CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time) AS Etime ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id, CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) RN
    INTO    #Turnedon
    FROM    @tmp AS T
    WHERE   T.event_value = 1
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    --create temp table for data 'turned off'
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Turnedoff') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Turnedoff
    SELECT  T.tag_id ,
            CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate ,
            CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time) AS Etime ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id, CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) RN
    INTO    #Turnedoff
    FROM    @tmp AS T
    WHERE   T.event_value = 0
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    --Create temp table for catalog with unique dates and tag_id
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Catalog') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Catalog
    SELECT DISTINCT
            T.tag_id ,
            CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate
    INTO    #Catalog
    FROM    @tmp AS T
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
/* 
row number helps to determine if on-off was done more than one time. 
so, if on-off was done more than once then you can aggregate (runtime) final result.
but also, it's better before aggregation insert data in temp table due to huge data amount
*/

    SELECT  C.tag_id ,
            C.Edate ,
            COALESCE(T.RN, 1) AS [event id] ,
            COALESCE(T.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00')) AS [turned on] ,
            COALESCE(T2.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59')) AS [turned off] ,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, COALESCE(T.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00')),
                     COALESCE(T2.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'))) Runtime
    FROM    #Catalog AS C
            LEFT JOIN #Turnedon AS T ON C.tag_id = T.tag_id
                                        AND C.Edate = T.Edate
            LEFT JOIN #Turnedoff AS T2 ON C.tag_id = T2.tag_id
                                          AND C.Edate = T2.Edate
                                          AND COALESCE(T.RN, 1) = T2.RN
```

---

[image: Snapshot with Values updated]

Comment: Oh this was so close!  But if you have more than one on/off event per day... it only counts the first one/off period.

Comment: @user1745767 this is because the data which been provided has two 'off(s)' in 2011-01-01 and 'no data' by 'turned on' in this date. mean that if motor was turned off once and not 'turned on' after that in same date before second 'off', then second 'off' cannot be applicable.

Comment: @user1745767 I put the snapshot for the normal situation, where you have two 'off' and one 'turned on' in same date, otherwise the second 'off' will be ignored.

Comment: The data set was a sample, I've got 500 million rows!  There are multiple on/off events per day.  I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: @user1745767, it will works with multiple on/offs too, if after 'off' will be 'turned on', otherwise will be ignored. for example "on-off-on-off-on" will works, "on-off-on-off-off" will works till third 'off' because of nodata against 'on' after 'off'. the last 'event id' number will show you the last 'off' without 'on' on this date

Comment: @user1745767, If you have missing 'on' after 'off' in multiple 'on/offs', then required to normalize data using additional query or whatever, e.g. if you have 'off' after another 'off', then insert 'on' equal to 'previous off'. e.g. if you have 'on-off-on-off-off' then it will be 'on-off-on-off-['on' equal to 'previous off']-off'. I will post another one answer with this example

Answer (score 0):

```
--in case when something like "off-off-on-off-of-on", just example of data normalization
 DECLARE    @tmp AS TABLE
        (
          tag_id INT ,
          event_time DATETIME ,
          event_value INT
        )
    INSERT  INTO @tmp
    VALUES  ( 10087, '2011-01-01 04:31:28.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-01 10:31:28.000', 0 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-01 18:03:28.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 02:35:27.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 07:35:27.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 11:07:27.000', 0 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-02 21:07:27.000', 0 )
    ,       ( 10087, '2011-01-03 10:39:27.000', 1 ),
            ( 10087, '2011-01-04 00:11:27.000', 1 )
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        --create temp table for data 'turned on'
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Turnedon') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Turnedon
    SELECT  T.tag_id ,
            T.Edate ,
            ( CASE WHEN t.event_value = 0
                        AND t.prev_event_value = 0 THEN t.prev_Etime
                   ELSE t.Etime
              END ) AS Etime ,
            ( CASE WHEN t.event_value = 0
                        AND t.prev_event_value = 0
                   THEN 'previous ''off'' was not executed'
                   ELSE NULL
              END ) AS event_desc ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id, Edate ORDER BY Etime ) RN
    INTO    #Turnedon
    FROM    ( SELECT    T.tag_id ,
                        CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate ,
                        CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time) AS Etime ,
                        T.event_value ,
                        lag(T.event_value) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id,
                                                  CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) AS prev_event_value ,
                        lag(CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time)) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id,
                                                                CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) AS prev_Etime
              FROM      @tmp AS T
            ) T
    WHERE   T.event_value = 1
            OR ( T.event_value = 0
                 AND T.prev_event_value = 0
               )
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        --create temp table for data 'turned off'
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Turnedoff') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Turnedoff
    SELECT  T.tag_id ,
            T.Edate ,
            ( CASE WHEN t.event_value = 1
                        AND t.prev_event_value = 1 THEN t.prev_Etime
                   ELSE t.Etime
              END ) AS Etime ,
            ( CASE WHEN t.event_value = 1
                        AND t.prev_event_value = 1
                   THEN '''on'' was not executed'
                   ELSE NULL
              END ) AS event_desc ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id, Edate ORDER BY Etime ) RN
    INTO    #Turnedoff
    FROM    ( SELECT    T.tag_id ,
                        CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate ,
                        CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time) AS Etime ,
                        T.event_value ,
                        lag(T.event_value) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id,
                                                  CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) AS prev_event_value ,
                        lag(CONVERT(TIME, T.event_time)) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.tag_id,
                                                                CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) ORDER BY T.event_time ) AS prev_Etime
              FROM      @tmp AS T
            ) T
    WHERE   T.event_value = 0
            OR ( T.event_value = 1
                 AND T.prev_event_value = 1
               )                                     
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        --Create temp table for catalog with unique dates and tag_id
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Catalog') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Catalog
    SELECT DISTINCT
            T.tag_id ,
            CONVERT(DATE, T.event_time) AS Edate
    INTO    #Catalog
    FROM    @tmp AS T
        -------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* 
    row number helps to determine if on-off was done more than one time. 
    so, if on-off was done more than once then you can aggregate (runtime) final result.
    but also, it's better before aggregation insert data in temp table due to huge data amount
    */       
    SELECT  C.tag_id ,
            C.Edate ,
            COALESCE(T.RN, 1) AS [event id] ,
            COALESCE(T.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00')) AS [turned on] ,
            COALESCE(T2.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59')) AS [turned off] ,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, COALESCE(T.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00')),
                     COALESCE(T2.Etime, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'))) Runtime ,
            COALESCE(t2.event_desc, t.event_desc, '') AS event_desc
    FROM    #Catalog AS C
            LEFT JOIN #Turnedon AS T ON C.tag_id = T.tag_id
                                        AND C.Edate = T.Edate
            LEFT JOIN #Turnedoff AS T2 ON C.tag_id = T2.tag_id
                                          AND C.Edate = T2.Edate
                                          AND COALESCE(T.RN, 1) = T2.RN
```

---

[image]